# Order of nodes in an XML document with XSD validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to validate an XML file with my application using XSD.
The problem is that I want an XML file without order in the nodes.
It seems I have 2 choices to build the xsd.

1. **Using `xs:all`** :  In this case there is no order of node but `maxOccurs="1"`
2. **Using `xs:sequence`** :  In this case there is no limit of `maxOccurs`,
   but an order in the nodes

Examples of nodes with problems: `export`, `lien_item`, `onglet_page`....

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Interface.xsd">
  <general>
    <theme>Windows8</theme>
    <photo>standard.png</photo>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <is_combo_interface_enabled>true</is_combo_interface_enabled>
    <appel champ="" tri="ASC" type="" visible="True" />
    <affiche_bloc_questionnaire>true</affiche_bloc_questionnaire>
    <affiche_kit_secours>false</affiche_kit_secours>
    <affiche_check_photos>true</affiche_check_photos>
    <affiche_btn_appel>true</affiche_btn_appel>
    <affiche_btn_auto>true</affiche_btn_auto>
    <affiche_btn_resultats_liste_resultats>true</affiche_btn_resultats_liste_resultats>
    <affichage_boutons_resultats>
      <tabexamen_btn_res_ind>true</tabexamen_btn_res_ind>
      <tabexamen_btn_res_col>true</tabexamen_btn_res_col>
      <tablistres_btn_res_ind>true</tablistres_btn_res_ind>
      <tablistres_btn_res_col>true</tablistres_btn_res_col>
      <tabtest_btn_res_ind>true</tabtest_btn_res_ind>
      <tabtest_btn_res_col>true</tabtest_btn_res_col>
    </affichage_boutons_resultats>
    <affiche_panel_bas>true</affiche_panel_bas>
    <affiche_btn_import>true</affiche_btn_import>
    <affiche_panel_examen>false</affiche_panel_examen>
    <edit_results>true</edit_results>
    <ajout_personne_autorise>true</ajout_personne_autorise>
    <suppression_personne_autorise>true</suppression_personne_autorise>
    <modifier_inscription_autorise>true</modifier_inscription_autorise>
    <signature_electronique>false</signature_electronique>
    <alerte_signature>false</alerte_signature>
    <nb_personnes_max>60</nb_personnes_max>
    <nb_menus>6</nb_menus>
    <nb_liens>4</nb_liens>
    <nb_champs_session>6</nb_champs_session>
    <nb_champs_personne>10</nb_champs_personne>
    <nb_champs_examen_res>0</nb_champs_examen_res>
    <export>
      <export_item num="1" adresse="" login="" password="" zip="true" chiffre="false" showform="true">MDB</export_item>
      <export_item num="2" adresse="" login="" password="" zip="true" chiffre="false" showform="true">XLS</export_item>
    </export>
    <menu>
      <menu_item num="1">
        <menu_action>CREER_SESSION</menu_action>
      </menu_item>
      <menu_item num="2">
        <menu_action>RECHERCHER</menu_action>
      </menu_item>
      <menu_item num="3">
        <menu_action>PARAMETRES</menu_action>
      </menu_item>
    </menu>
    <onglet>
      <onglet_page num="1">
        <onglet_visible>true</onglet_visible>
      </onglet_page>
      <onglet_page num="2">
        <onglet_visible>false</onglet_visible>
      </onglet_page>
    </onglet>
    <default_import_directory></default_import_directory>
    <default_import_file></default_import_file>
    <default_export_directory></default_export_directory>
    <lien>
      <lien_item num="1">
        <text>ASSISTANCE</text>
        <action>1.exe</action>
      </lien_item>
      <lien_item num="2">
        <text>WEB</text>
        <action>2.exe</action>
      </lien_item>
      <lien_item num="3">
        <text>NEWS</text>
        <action>version_contenu.txt</action>
      </lien_item>
      <lien_item num="4">
        <text>AIDE</text>
        <action>Aide\Qui.chm</action>
      </lien_item>
    </lien>
  </general>
  <!-- nom_champ_session = Libellé du label du groupbox session -->
  <session>
    <champ_session num="1">
      <nom_champ_session>LIB_SESSION</nom_champ_session>
      <controle_session num="1">
        <obligatoire_champ_session>true</obligatoire_champ_session>
        <type_controle_session>textbox</type_controle_session>
        <longueur_controle_session>150</longueur_controle_session>
        <donnees_controle_session>texte</donnees_controle_session>
        <propertie_session>Libelle</propertie_session>
        <modifiable_champ_session>true</modifiable_champ_session>
      </controle_session>
    </champ_session>
    <champ_session num="2">
      <nom_champ_session>CHOIX_EXAMEN</nom_champ_session>
      <controle_session num="1">
        <obligatoire_champ_session>false</obligatoire_champ_session>
        <type_controle_session>dropdownlist</type_controle_session>
        <longueur_controle_session>150</longueur_controle_session>
        <donnees_controle_session>texte</donnees_controle_session>
        <propertie_session>cboExamen</propertie_session>
        <modifiable_champ_session>true</modifiable_champ_session>
      </controle_session>
    </champ_session>
    <champ_session num="3">
      <nom_champ_session>LIB_FORMATION</nom_champ_session>
      <controle_session num="1">
        <obligatoire_champ_session>false</obligatoire_champ_session>
        <type_controle_session>textbox</type_controle_session>
        <longueur_controle_session>150</longueur_controle_session>
        <donnees_controle_session>texte</donnees_controle_session>
        <propertie_session>NomFormation</propertie_session>
        <modifiable_champ_session>true</modifiable_champ_session>
      </controle_session>
    </champ_session>
    <champ_session num="4">
      <nom_champ_session>DATES_SESSION</nom_champ_session>
      <controle_session num="1">
        <obligatoire_champ_session>false</obligatoire_champ_session>
        <type_controle_session>datetimepicker</type_controle_session>
        <longueur_controle_session>90</longueur_controle_session>
        <donnees_controle_session>date</donnees_controle_session>
        <propertie_session>DateDebut</propertie_session>
        <modifiable_champ_session>true</modifiable_champ_session>
      </controle_session>
      <controle_session num="2">
        <obligatoire_champ_session>false</obligatoire_champ_session>
        <type_controle_session>datetimepicker</type_controle_session>
        <longueur_controle_session>90</longueur_controle_session>
        <donnees_controle_session>date</donnees_controle_session>
        <propertie_session>DateFin</propertie_session>
        <modifiable_champ_session>true</modifiable_champ_session>
      </controle_session>
    </champ_session>
    <champ_session num="5">
      <nom_champ_session>LIEU_FORMATION</nom_champ_session>
      <controle_session num="1">
        <obligatoire_champ_session>false</obligatoire_champ_session>
        <type_controle_session>dropdown</type_controle_session>
        <longueur_controle_session>150</longueur_controle_session>
        <donnees_controle_session>texte</donnees_controle_session>
        <propertie_session>LieuFormation</propertie_session>
        <modifiable_champ_session>true</modifiable_champ_session>
        <type_datasource_session>BDD</type_datasource_session>
        <valeur_datasource_session>tSession.LieuFormation</valeur_datasource_session>
        <affichage_datasource_session>tSession.LieuFormation</affichage_datasource_session>
      </controle_session>
    </champ_session>
    <champ_session num="6">
      <nom_champ_session>RESPONSABLE_FORMATION</nom_champ_session>
      <controle_session num="1">
        <obligatoire_champ_session>false</obligatoire_champ_session>
        <type_controle_session>dropdown</type_controle_session>
        <longueur_controle_session>150</longueur_controle_session>
        <donnees_controle_session>texte</donnees_controle_session>
        <propertie_session>Formateur</propertie_session>
        <modifiable_champ_session>true</modifiable_champ_session>
        <type_datasource_session>BDD</type_datasource_session>
        <valeur_datasource_session>tSession.Formateur</valeur_datasource_session>
        <affichage_datasource_session>tSession.IdFormateur</affichage_datasource_session>
      </controle_session>
    </champ_session>
  </session>
  <personne>
    <champ_personne num="1">
      <nom_champ_personne>KEY</nom_champ_personne>
      <obligatoire_champ_personne>false</obligatoire_champ_personne>
      <mode_grille_fiche_personne>LES2</mode_grille_fiche_personne>
      <controle_personne>
        <type_controle_personne>textbox</type_controle_personne>
        <longueur_controle_personne>0</longueur_controle_personne>
        <donnees_controle_personne>texte</donnees_controle_personne>
        <propertie_personne>Key</propertie_personne>
        <modifiable_personne>true</modifiable_personne>
      </controle_personne>
    </champ_personne>
    <champ_personne num="2">
      <nom_champ_personne>PRESENCE</nom_champ_personne>
      <obligatoire_champ_personne>false</obligatoire_champ_personne>
      <mode_grille_fiche_personne>grille</mode_grille_fiche_personne>
      <controle_personne>
        <type_controle_personne>checkbox</type_controle_personne>
        <longueur_controle_personne>30</longueur_controle_personne>
        <donnees_controle_personne>texte</donnees_controle_personne>
        <propertie_personne>Present</propertie_personne>
        <modifiable_personne>true</modifiable_personne>
      </controle_personne>
    </champ_personne>
    <champ_personne num="3">
      <nom_champ_personne>PHOTO</nom_champ_personne>
      <obligatoire_champ_personne>false</obligatoire_champ_personne>
      <mode_grille_fiche_personne>FICHE</mode_grille_fiche_personne>
      <controle_personne>
        <type_controle_personne>image</type_controle_personne>
        <longueur_controle_personne>50</longueur_controle_personne>
        <donnees_controle_personne>texte</donnees_controle_personne>
        <propertie_personne>Photo</propertie_personne>
        <modifiable_personne>true</modifiable_personne>
      </controle_personne>
    </champ_personne>
    <champ_personne num="4">
      <nom_champ_personne>NOM</nom_champ_personne>
      <obligatoire_champ_personne>true</obligatoire_champ_personne>
      <mode_grille_fiche_personne>LES2</mode_grille_fiche_personne>
      <controle_personne>
        <type_controle_personne>textbox</type_controle_personne>
        <longueur_controle_personne>100</longueur_controle_personne>
        <donnees_controle_personne>texte</donnees_controle_personne>
        <propertie_personne>Nom</propertie_personne>
        <modifiable_personne>true</modifiable_personne>
      </controle_personne>
    </champ_personne>
  </personne>
    <examen>
        <examen_lib num="1">R372m</examen_lib>
        <examen_lib num="2">R386</examen_lib>
        <examen_lib num="3">R389</examen_lib>
        <examen_lib num="4">R390</examen_lib>
        <examen_lib num="5">LV 22 R389</examen_lib>
        <examen_lib num="6">LV 32 R389</examen_lib>
        <examen_lib num="7">LV 42 R389</examen_lib>
        <examen_lib num="8">LV 14 R386</examen_lib>
        <examen_lib num="9">LV 24 R386</examen_lib>
    </examen>
</interface>
```

The XSD meant to validate the above XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="interface" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Interface.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/Interface.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Interface.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="interface" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="general">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element name="theme" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="photo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="is_combo_interface_enabled" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="appel" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                         <!-- <xs:extension base="xs:string">-->
                            <xs:attribute name="champ" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="tri" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="type" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="visible" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                          <!--</xs:extension>-->
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="affiche_bloc_questionnaire" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="affiche_kit_secours" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="affiche_check_photos" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="affiche_btn_appel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="affiche_btn_auto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="affiche_btn_resultats_liste_resultats" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

              <xs:element name="affichage_boutons_resultats" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="tabexamen_btn_res_ind" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="tabexamen_btn_res_col" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1"/>
                        <xs:element name="tablistres_btn_res_ind" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2"/>
                        <xs:element name="tablistres_btn_res_col" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="3"/>
                        <xs:element name="tabtest_btn_res_ind" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="4"/>
                        <xs:element name="tabtest_btn_res_col" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="5"/>
                      </xs:sequence>
                 </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="affiche_panel_bas" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="affiche_btn_import" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="affiche_panel_examen" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="build" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="edit_results" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="ajout_personne_autorise" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="suppression_personne_autorise" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="modifier_inscription_autorise" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="signature_electronique" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="alerte_signature" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="nb_personnes_max" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="nb_menus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="nb_liens" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="nb_champs_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="nb_champs_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="nb_champs_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="export" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="export_item" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="export_item_Text" msdata:Ordinal="4">
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="num" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="adresse" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="login" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="password" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="zip" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="chiffre" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="showform" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="maille" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="argument1" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="local_directory" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="menu" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="menu_item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="menu_action" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="num" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="onglet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="onglet_page" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="onglet_visible" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="num" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="import" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="import_item" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" msdata:Ordinal="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="import_item_Text" msdata:Ordinal="2">
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="num" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="type" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="default_import_directory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="default_import_file" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="default_export_directory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="lien" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="lien_item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                          <xs:element name="action" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="num" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="session">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="champ_session" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="nom_champ_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                    <xs:element name="controle_session" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="obligatoire_champ_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                          <xs:element name="type_controle_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                          <xs:element name="longueur_controle_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
                          <xs:element name="donnees_controle_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
                          <xs:element name="propertie_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
                          <xs:element name="modifiable_champ_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="5" />
                          <xs:element name="type_datasource_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="6" />
                          <xs:element name="valeur_datasource_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="7" />
                          <xs:element name="affichage_datasource_session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="8" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="num" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="num" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="personne">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="champ_personne" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="nom_champ_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                    <xs:element name="obligatoire_champ_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                    <xs:element name="mode_grille_fiche_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
                    <xs:element name="controle_personne" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="type_controle_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="longueur_controle_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="donnees_controle_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="propertie_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="type_datasource_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="valeur_datasource_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="affichage_datasource_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="modifiable_personne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="num" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="examen">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="examen_lib" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="examen_lib_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute name="num" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="examen_res">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="champ_examen_res" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="nom_champ_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                    <xs:element name="obligatoire_champ_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                    <xs:element name="controle_examen_res" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="type_controle_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="longueur_controle_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="donnees_controle_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="propertie_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="type_datasource_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="valeur_datasource_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="affichage_datasource_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="modifiable_examen_res" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="num" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>


      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Have you got an idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can get xs:all to work if you simply get rid of the maxOccurs ="unbounded" on your onglet, lien, and export elements. These elements are not repeated in your sample, even though their child elements still contain unbounded collections.

Also, for ease of reading and cleaner code generation with tools like JAXB and xsd.exe, I prefer to refer to named complexType elements extensively.  For example:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="http://foo.bar"
       xmlns:myprefix="http://foo.bar"
>
<!-- ... -->

<xs:complexType name="export">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="export_item">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
          <xs:attribute name="adresse" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          <xs:attribute name="login" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          <xs:attribute name="password" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          <xs:attribute name="zip" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
          <xs:attribute name="chiffre" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
          <xs:attribute name="showform" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- ... -->

<xs:all>
  <!-- ... -->
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="relation" type="myprefix:lien"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="export" type="myprefix:export"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</xs:all>
```

(In production code, I actually tend not to use inline xs:complexType at all, and would instead re-factor out a  named export_item type from the above.)

Comment: thanks for answering, it seems to be a solution. I check "answered" cause i need to work on another project during some days. I'll test it after :)

Answer (score 1):

You will receive errors along the lines of the following provided by Xerces-J when you try to validate your XML against your XSD:

> [Error] try.xsd:15:21: cos-all-limited.2: The {max occurs} of an
>   element in an 'all' model group must be 0 or 1. The value 'unbounded'
>   for element 'appel' is invalid.

**This is a proper error message.**  You cannot use `xsd:all` if you want any of its elements to be repeated.

The way forward is to **abandon the need to support unordered elements** via `xsd:all` and use `xsd:sequence` instead.  While imposing an ordering on elements may appear to be non-ideal, in practice ordered elements work fine and avoid problems with cardinality (as above) and [Unique Particle Attribution](http://www.w3.org/wiki/UniqueParticleAttribution) violations (common when trying to skirt above problem via `xsd:choice`).

Comment: The xml file is made by hand, but now used in a program that serialize/deserialize this file to use/modify it. When the file is written, nodes are put in any order by VB.net I do not hand over the writting process.:/

Comment: If a single program is writing the XML, it probably has an (arbitrarily) defined ordering; just use that order.  It would be odd for the program to use a data-dependent or non-deterministic ordering.   If multiple programs are already dependent on conflicting orderings AND also are dependent upon cardinality constraints greater than one as you describe above, then you've waiting too long to impose a policy enforceable by XSD 1.0.

Comment: I think that where you say `" you cannot use xsd:all if you want more than one of its elements to be repeated"` it should be `you cannot use xsd:all if you want one or more of its elements to be repeated more than one time`.

Comment: @sergioFC, agreed; it is awkwardly written.   Updated to simply *you cannot use `xsd:all` if you want any of its elements to be repeated.*  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
          <!-- XML Schema Generated from XML Document on Mon Jun 01 2015 16:20:21 GMT+0200 -->
          <!-- with XmlGrid.net Free Online Service http://xmlgrid.net -->
       <xs:element name="interface">
              <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="general">
                                   <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:sequence>
                                                 <xs:element name="theme" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="photo" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="version" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="is_combo_interface_enabled" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="appel">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                               <xs:attribute name="champ" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                               <xs:attribute name="tri" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                               <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                               <xs:attribute name="visible" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="affiche_bloc_questionnaire" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="affiche_kit_secours" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="affiche_check_photos" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="affiche_btn_appel" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="affiche_btn_auto" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="affiche_btn_resultats_liste_resultats" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="affichage_boutons_resultats">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                               <xs:sequence>
                                                                      <xs:element name="tabexamen_btn_res_ind" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                      <xs:element name="tabexamen_btn_res_col" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                      <xs:element name="tablistres_btn_res_ind" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                      <xs:element name="tablistres_btn_res_col" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                      <xs:element name="tabtest_btn_res_ind" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                      <xs:element name="tabtest_btn_res_col" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                  </xs:sequence>
                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="affiche_panel_bas" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="affiche_btn_import" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="affiche_panel_examen" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="edit_results" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="ajout_personne_autorise" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="suppression_personne_autorise" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="modifier_inscription_autorise" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="signature_electronique" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="alerte_signature" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="nb_personnes_max" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="nb_menus" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="nb_liens" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="nb_champs_session" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="nb_champs_personne" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="nb_champs_examen_res" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="export">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                               <xs:sequence>
                                                                      <xs:element name="export_item" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string">
                                                                             <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="adresse" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="login" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="password" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="zip" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="chiffre" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="showform" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                         </xs:element>
                                                                  </xs:sequence>
                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="menu">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                               <xs:sequence>
                                                                      <xs:element name="menu_item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                             <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="menu_action" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                       </xs:sequence>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                         </xs:element>
                                                                  </xs:sequence>
                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="onglet">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                               <xs:sequence>
                                                                      <xs:element name="onglet_page" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                             <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="onglet_visible" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                       </xs:sequence>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                         </xs:element>
                                                                  </xs:sequence>
                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="default_import_directory"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="default_import_file"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="default_export_directory"></xs:element>
                                                 <xs:element name="lien">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                               <xs:sequence>
                                                                      <xs:element name="lien_item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                             <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="action" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                       </xs:sequence>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                         </xs:element>
                                                                  </xs:sequence>
                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                             </xs:sequence>
                                      </xs:complexType>
                               </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="session">
                                   <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:sequence>
                                                 <xs:element name="champ_session" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                               <xs:sequence>
                                                                      <xs:element name="nom_champ_session" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                      <xs:element name="controle_session">
                                                                             <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="obligatoire_champ_session" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="type_controle_session" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="longueur_controle_session" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="donnees_controle_session" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="propertie_session" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="modifiable_champ_session" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                       </xs:sequence>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                         </xs:element>
                                                                  </xs:sequence>
                                                               <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                             </xs:sequence>
                                      </xs:complexType>
                               </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="personne">
                                   <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:sequence>
                                                 <xs:element name="champ_personne" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                               <xs:sequence>
                                                                      <xs:element name="nom_champ_personne" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                      <xs:element name="obligatoire_champ_personne" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                      <xs:element name="mode_grille_fiche_personne" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                      <xs:element name="controle_personne">
                                                                             <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="type_controle_personne" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="longueur_controle_personne" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="donnees_controle_personne" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="propertie_personne" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                           <xs:element name="modifiable_personne" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                       </xs:sequence>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                         </xs:element>
                                                                  </xs:sequence>
                                                               <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                             </xs:sequence>
                                      </xs:complexType>
                               </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="examen">
                                   <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:sequence>
                                                 <xs:element name="examen_lib" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                               <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                             </xs:sequence>
                                      </xs:complexType>
                               </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                     <xs:attribute name="xmlns" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                 </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>
```

This is the XSD generated from your XML file using http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html

Comment: Thanks for answering, but doesn't validate file even if nodes are ordered :/